# Child Theme Not Overriding Parent Theme

Tags: functions, themes, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, css

I know this question has been asked many times. I even spent the entire day yesterday getting things to work but to no avail. I am pretty sure I am missing out on something small//silly but I am unable to figure it out.

So, here is my question:
I have purchased the Identity-vcard theme from Envato and I want to make some modifications to the child theme without disturbing the parent theme. But the style.css of the child theme is not loading/overriding the parent’s.
I am using this in the functions.php

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = ‘Identity-vcard-style’;

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘/style.css’ );
    wp_enqueue_style( ‘Identity-vcard-child-style’, get_stylesheet_uri() . ‘/style.css’, array( $parent_style ) );
}
add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘my_theme_enqueue_styles’ );
```

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are using `get_stylesheet_uri()` which links directly to your stylesheet, then your adding /style.css which is resulting in an invalid url.

So you need to remove the `/style.css`.

Or use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and leave the `/style.css` on there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() in child theme and make sure that the parent theme is using get_template_directory_uri().

If the parent theme is not using get_template_directory_uri() you'll have to unregister the main style and register it again in your child theme.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Registering and then queuing. Plus I had to register all the stylesheets since the theme uses more than one. Worked!

Comment: Cool, can you give me an up and select my answer as correct, please?